# make content div fill remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have a page layout in which I have a `fixed` header which can have any height and a footer positioned at the bottom of the page. I'm looking for a css solution so that the content div fills the remaining space (vertically). In the jsfiddle below I've tried to do this, but as you can see the content is behind the footer.

HTML:

```
<main>
    <header>
        <ol>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>foo</li>
        </ol>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div class="content"><div>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color: #abc;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

html, body, main, section {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.content{
   background-color: #000; 
   height: 100%;
}

footer {
    background-color: #def;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 54px;
    position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
```

}

Is this possible with pure css(3) ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dohqn8m4/)

Comment: Is your layout responsive?

Comment: yes, the layout is actually fluid

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of an ugly solution, but if you make the margin-top of the content div as -54px and add a div inside it with padding-top:54px, it works as expected.

HTML:

```
 <div class="content"><div class="contentwrapper"></div><div>
```

CSS:

```
.contentwrapper {
    padding-top:54px;
}
.content{
   background-color: #000; 
   height: 100%;
   margin-top:-54px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dohqn8m4/1/

Comment: I think that your solution fixes the footer issue, but now the content gets behind the header

Comment: That is the same as before, in your script the content was behind the header as well

Comment: Unless you have a fixed height for your header, this can also not really be solved by just using css

Answer (score 1):

Here a diffrent approach:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <ol>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foo</li>
    </ol>
</header>
<main>
    <section>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </section>

    <div class="push"></div>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }

    header {
        background-color: #abc;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    main {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        margin-bottom: -54px;
    }

    main > section{
        padding-top: 72px;
    }

    .content {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .push {
        height: 54px;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #def;
        height: 54px;
    }
```

Now the footer is always at the bottom aslong the content doesn't fill the hole page. In that case the "push" element provides enough space to deny overlapping of footer and content.

Your content div ist now placed under the footer through the padding. The height is actually 0 because of missing content. In my approach the content div fits always the content inserted.

Keep in mind that
a) for responsive purpose you had to know about the header height and adjust the padding of the section using media queries
b) the same for the footer. Adjust the height of the push element and adjust the margin-bottom value.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/sf7ext2r/)

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning the `content` to be right above the footer

```
bottom: <footer-height>;
position: absolute;
```

Comment: if I do that I don't get a div that fills the whole space (even not with height set at 100%)

Answer (score 0):

I made sticky footer using this [tutorial](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/). I think it's easy and convenient to use.

**CSS CODE**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <article>Lorem ipsum...</article>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO URL](http://mystrd.at/data/sticky_footer.html)**